# can I declare multiple variable in loop with ## in c preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I know this probably isn't applied way for declaring variable but I'm curious it is possible or not

```
#define paste(front,back) front ## back
int main(int argc,int *argv[]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
       int paste(var,i) = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know arrays but as I said I'm curious :)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 misunderstandings.

- macro is just doing text substitution, nothing magic. in your case, the line with macro will be literally `int vari = i;`. Thus you can always predict its effect.
- Declaring variable is a compile time action, `for` loop execution is at runtime. Declaring multiple variables with a `for` loop is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This macro will indeed declare a variable, but with fixed name `vari` because macros are evaluated as a first step of compilation and do not exists at runtime. And it will be destroyed at each iteration of the loop because it immediately goes out of scope.

Declaring variables at runtime is not possible because C is a compiled language and variables (and macros) only really exists in source code. It is possible to write a fancy macro that will expand into several variables but their names and count will be still fixed at compile time.